# Pandas is not working, even after I installed it

Tags: python, pandas

I currently need to use pandas with Thonny, because pandas is installed locally there, but all my coding is in visual studio and i want to be able to use pandas in the editor i like. I have this error while trying to run a code for pandas.

```
No module named 'pandas'
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/Ambassador.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
```

Even tho i have already installed it, i've made several attempts with pip, conda, i installed wheel and everything suggested.

Anyone knows why is this ?

for additional info i have a Mac

Comment: Might you have different versions of python on your computer?

Comment: Your VSCode is probably using a different python interpreter than the one you installed `pandas` in. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Check python version where pandas is installed and use same version to run your code

Answer (score 0):

It could be cause you have installed pandas at the different virtual environment. I guess, you should try to check and change environment (⇧⌘P) in visual studio especially if you are using things like conda.

Also, check it for info about environments: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments